# i want to seamlessly connect a known parabola with an unknown sine wave at a specific x coordinate

Tags: calculus

The known parabola's equation is (x-(-5√3+127/8))^2+((505√3)/4)-(14337/64)
and the unknown sine function is sin(bx+c).
I am needing to find b and c that will allow for a seamless transition with the known parabola above at x=10.

For context, this is to form a roller coaster track.

I attempt the basic f(x)=g(x) solving for the equation at x=10 , then f'(x) =g'(x) solving for the equation at x=10 then putting both equation and solving simultaneously for b and c, however that proved no solution.

- Step 1: Find the value of the known parabola function at x = 10: Substitute x = 10 into the parabola function: f(x) = (x - (-5√3 + 127/8))^2 + ((505√3)/4) - (14337/64) f(10) = (10 - (-5√3 + 127/8))^2 + ((505√3)/4) - (14337/64).
- Step 2: Find the derivative of the known parabola function: f'(x) = 2(x - (-5√3 + 127/8))
- Step 3: Find the value of the derivative of the known parabola function at x = 10: f'(10) = 2(10 - (-5√3 + 127/8))
- Step 4: Set up equations to ensure seamless transition: We want the sin function sin(bx + c) to have the same value and derivative as the parabola function at x = 10. Equation 1: $\sin(10b + c) = f(10)$ Equation 2: $b\cos(10b + c) = f'(10).$
- Step 5: Solve for the values of b and c: Use Equations 1 and 2 to solve for the values of b and c. You may need to use numerical methods or approximation techniques, as these equations might not have simple closed-form solutions. Once you have the values of b and c, you can use them in the sin function sin(bx + c) to seamlessly connect the parabola and the sine function at x = 10, creating a smooth transition for your roller coaster track. But this also proved no solution.

Comment: I attempt the basic f(x)=g(x) solving for the equation at x=10 , then f'(x) =g'(x) solving for the equation at x=10 then putting both equation and solving simultaneously for b and c, however that proved no solution

Comment: I edited your post to include your comments about your attempts. Please delete them from here, and [format them there](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value of your equation at $x=10$ is $\left(10-\left(-5\sqrt{3}+\frac{127}{8}\right)\right)^2+\frac{505\sqrt{3}}{4}-\frac{14337}{64}\approx2.41342$. The goal would be to take the derivatives of both equations, and set them equal. However, a function of the form $\sin(bx+c)$ lives strictly between $-1$ and $1$, so it cannot possibly connect with the function at $x=10$. You will need to include a third variable $d$, and try to connect your curve smoothly to $\sin(bx+c)+d$ at $x=10$. There will be infinitely many solutions for $b,c,d$ to this equation, so I won't try writing them down.

Comment: thank you so much now I get why it hasn't been working :)

Comment: @rose There are multiple ways to go about finding a solution. Note that $d$ must be within approximately the interval $[1.41342,3.41342]$, since the sine wave will not be able to reach the point $2.41342$ otherwise. If you choose $d$ within this range, then you may be able to solve for $b$ and $c$, though your solutions may be decimal approximations.

Comment: One can also scale the sin function instead of shifting its value

Comment: @rose It may also be easier to use an amplitude $a$ as follows: $a\sin(bx+c)$, instead of using $d$.

Comment: yes I might do the amplitude instead thank you so much has helped heaps :)